# Formateo de números con 2 decimales OpenXml C#

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

Estoy intentando enmarcar los números de un archivo excel, con la librería OpenXML en C#, con un formato de 2 decimales.
Lo que me ocurre, es que pareciera que no me estaría tomando el formatCode del numberingFormat, ya que me devuelve todos los números como enteros.

A continuación les dejo mi código para la aplicación del estilo según la columna y/o fila:

```
if (rowNum == 1 && isFirstRowHeader)
                {
                    attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("s", null, "2"));
                }
                else if (isNumber)
                {
                    attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("s", null, "3"));
                }
                else
                {
                    attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("s", null, "1"));
                }
```

Acá le doy el formato de salida que quiero que tenga mi número o string:

```
if (isNumber)
                {
                    writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(string.Format("{0:0.00}",notCurrencyString)));
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(string.Format(cellValue)));
                }
```

Y acá genero los estilos:

```
public Stylesheet GenerateStylesheet()
    {

        uint iExcelIndex = 164;

        var fonts = new Fonts(
            new Font( // Index 0 - default
                new FontSize() { Val = 10 }

            ),
            new Font( // Index 1 - header
                new FontSize() { Val = 10 },
                new Bold(),
                new Color() { Rgb = "FFFFFF" }

            ));

        var fills = new Fills(
            new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None }), // Index 0 - default
            new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 }), // Index 1 - default
            new Fill(new PatternFill(new ForegroundColor { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "66666666" } })
            { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid }), // Index 2 - header
            new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None  }) // Index 3 - currency cells
        );

        var numberingFormat = new NumberingFormat {
            NumberFormatId = 1,
            FormatCode = "#,##0.00"
        };

        var borders = new Borders(
            new Border(), // index 0 default
            new Border( // index 1 black border
                new LeftBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                new RightBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                new TopBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                new BottomBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                new DiagonalBorder())
        );

        var cellFormats = new CellFormats(
            new CellFormat(), // default
            new CellFormat
            {
                FontId = 0,
                FillId = 0,
                BorderId = 1,
                ApplyBorder = true
            }, // body
            new CellFormat
            {
                FontId = 1,
                FillId = 2,
                BorderId = 1,
                ApplyFill = true
            }, // header
            new CellFormat
            {
                NumberFormatId = 1,
                FontId = 0,
                FillId = 2,
                BorderId = 1,
                ApplyBorder = true,
                ApplyNumberFormat = true
            } // currency
        );

        var formattedCells = new Stylesheet(fonts, fills, borders, cellFormats, numberingFormat);
        return formattedCells;
    }
```

Intenté probar con los distintos formateos que encontré por Internet, pero ninguno me funcionó. Si alguno me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver!
Básicamente, cada formateo que se desea hacer, tiene su propio id.
Yo intentando formatearlo con el id 1, cuando el id correcto para este tipo de número con 2 decimales, es el 4.
Acá les dejo el link de donde saqué mi información: [Click aquí](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/NumberFormatId-Lookup-Table)

En este caso, mi código quedó así:

```
var numberingFormat = new NumberingFormat {
            NumberFormatId = 4,
            FormatCode = "#,##0.00"
        };
```

Comment: De ese enlace, extrae el ejemplo que necesites, de este modo, se mantiene la información en caso el link expire :)